# How to enable debug in Semantic-UI-React?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I'm using Semantic-UI in my react project.
It works well. but sometimes it shows error in during unit testing with Jest.

This is the error message

```
console.error node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/lib/debug.js:25
      Semantic-UI-React could not enable debug.
    console.error node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/lib/debug.js:26
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'debug' of undefined
          at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/lib/debug.js:22:33)
          at Runtime._execModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:513:13)
          at Runtime.requireModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:329:14)
          at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:405:19)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/lib/index.js:77:14)
          at Runtime._execModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:513:13)
          at Runtime.requireModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:329:14)
          at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:405:19)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/addons/Responsive/Responsive.js:43:12)
          at Runtime._execModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:513:13)
          at Runtime.requireModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:329:14)
          at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:405:19)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/addons/Responsive/index.js:8:19)
          at Runtime._execModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:513:13)
          at Runtime.requireModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:329:14)
          at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:405:19)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/commonjs/index.js:7:19)
          at Runtime._execModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:513:13)
          at Runtime.requireModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:329:14)
          at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:405:19)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/src/FamilyViewWithController/index.js:4:24)
          at Runtime._execModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:513:13)
          at Runtime.requireModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:329:14)
          at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:405:19)
          at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/src/FamilyViewWithController/index.test.js:1:232)
          at Runtime._execModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:513:13)
          at Runtime.requireModule (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:329:14)
          at jasmine2 (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:97:11)
          at runTest (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/build/runTest.js:85:10)
          at module.exports (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/jest-cli/build/TestWorker.js:87:5)
          at handle (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:44:8)
          at process.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/work/node/suite/suite-cloud-app/client/node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:51:3)
          at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
          at process.emit (events.js:214:7)
          at emit (internal/child_process.js:772:12)
          at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

It's very wierd.
- sometimes it appears, sometimes it doesn't
- sometimes it appears in a component, sometimes it doesn't appear in that component.
- it doesn't appear with small amount of components. but it appears with a lot of components.
- but the tests always are passed even if this issue appears.

The test command that I'm using is

```
CI=true NODE_ENV=test react-scripts test --env=jsdom --no-cache
```

any thoughts about that? I do want your team to solve this issue or let me know how to fix it.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, was fixed in https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/pull/3485 and released in 0.86.0.